# How to set in different values in a cell which has "Data Validation" and take the sum

Tags: excel, sum, conditional-statements

I have an Excel file... in sheet1, I have cell A1 which is one of a list of values I created using "Data Validation"... say A1 could be A, B, C and D... and the rest of Sheet1 is data conditional on the content in cell A1.

Now in Sheet2, I want to calculate sum of B3 in sheet1 while A1 in Sheet1 takes the value of A and B. What can I do to realize this?

To better show the problem, A1 has a drop-down meny and could be one of I1:I4 and B1 is set equal to A1. Now I want to sum up B1 while A1 takes each value inside I1:I4. How should I do that?

Many thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rfIL.png)

Comment: your problem is hard to follow through words alone.  Please include a mock up of the data and expected outcome.

Comment: did. @ScottCraner

Comment: `B1` is just one cell - how can you sum that up?

Comment: You will want vba, in a worksheet_Change event to do this.  While it can be done with formula it would require the need to turn off certain warnings over the entire workbook.

Comment: @Prasanna Yes, but when A1 takes on each of the 4 values, B1 will aslo do and I want to take a sum of them...

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, I can use a VBA to set the value of A1 to be 1, but how can I take the resulting value of B1 and move on to set the value of A1 to be 2, 3 and 4...

Comment: No you use a worksheet_change event, so when ever A1 changes it fires the event and adds the value to the value already in B1.

Comment: @ScottCraner Can you give more details? Sorry I have never used this function before...